# Is it possible to make a quiz app without writing any code in Xcode at all?

Tags: ios, xcode

Is it possible to make a quiz app without writing any code in Xcode at all, just using the story board feature?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Storyboard:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/Storyboard.html)

> A storyboard is a visual representation of the user interface of an
>   iOS application, showing screens of content and the connections
>   between those screens. A storyboard is composed of a sequence of
>   scenes, each of which represents a view controller and its views;
>   scenes are connected by segue objects, which represent a transition
>   between two view controllers.

Without logic you will not be able to create anything useful or engaging. How would you tally a score? Track results/improvements? Randomize the questions to prevent the user from just memorizing the answers? The only kind of quiz/game I can think of you could possibly make using only storyboard would be to create a view with some text saying "You Passed" and then creating other static views with questions and buttons. When the user selects the correct button for the answer then segue to the next question otherwise segue to a "You Failed" view. This would require the user to have to get all the questions correct to pass.

**Update:**

Added an example on [GitHub](https://github.com/JHumphreyJr/CodelessQuiz) of a simple quiz made only in storyboard. You will notice that the navigation is terrible as a result of no added code.

Comment: Yeah this true,only a very basic quiz you can make without code, even if you use checkpoints every 10 questions (when they fail)! So I need to create a new subclass for every question?

Comment: Storyboard may not be the way to go for a quiz. What you will want is to design a generic view that can display questions and answer options. Then in the view controller for this view you can accept a generic question object that you create and display the question text and options choices. It will then be up to you how you want to track the score.

Comment: @George I've added an example project using only storyboard allowing you to see the limitations.

Comment: Yeah, I saw it, it's not that bad though...!